# Create work instructions with Unity and Excel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for help to import excel files to unity. And instantiate UI prefabs by analysing the excel data. Has someone done a similar project and can provide me with scripts to import excel data to unity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found how to parse an excel to unity here: http://codesaying.com/unity-parse-excel-in-unity3d/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).